# Javascript - função math.log() não carrega

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

Estou com o seguinte problema. Estou criando um botão para calular logaritmo dentro de uma calculadora. então achei no link nesse [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) a possibilidade de fazer o calulo. Desde já agradeço a ajuda. O resultado era para ser exibido no visor mas fica tudo vazio.

```
function logaritmo( x, y) {
return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
}
```

Mas quero que função acima seja executada no algoritmo abaixo.

```
function calculoLogaritmo() {
var vis = document.calcform.visor;
var element = document.getElementById('elemento');
var logaritmo = document.getElementById('log');
var base = document.getElementById('base');
var resultado;
element.innerHTML = 'O logaritmo de <input id="log" type="text"/> na base   <input id="base" type="text"/> ';
if(isNaN(Number(logaritmo.value)) && isNaN(Number(base.value)) || Number(logaritmo.value) == "" && Number(base.value) == "" ){
alert("Favor informa valores validos para a execução do resultado");
} else{
resultado = logaritmo(Number(base.value), Number(logaritmo.value));
}
vis.value = resultado;

}
```

Segue o html

```
<form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
<p id="elemento"></p>
     <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value=""/>
<td><input type="button" name="logaritmo" class="formula" value="log" title="logaritmo" onclick="calculoLogaritmo()" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: E qual o comportamento que era esperado? Qual o comportamento que está ocorrendo?

Comment: O comportamento esperado era que aparece no visor o resultado mas o mesmo fica vazio.

Comment: Coloca essa informação na sua pergunta então

Comment: O nome `logaritmo` é usado 2x no seu código, tanto para a função que você está usando para fazer o cálculo quanto para o elemento HTML que você está pegando com `document.getElementById()`. Esse pode ser seu problema, renomeie um dos dois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tinha colocado uma variável com o mesmo nome da função e também não tinha criado ainda os elementos. Corrigindo teremos:

```js
function calcular(x, y) {
  return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
}

function calculoLogaritmo() {
  var vis = document.getElementById('visor');
  var element = document.getElementById('elemento');
  var logaritmo = document.getElementById('log').value;
  var base = document.getElementById('base').value;
  var resultado;
  element.innerHTML = `O logaritmo de ${logaritmo} na base   ${base} `;
  if (isNaN(Number(logaritmo)) && isNaN(Number(base)) || Number(logaritmo) == "" && Number(base) == "") {
    alert("Favor informa valores validos para a execução do resultado");
  } else {
    resultado = calcular(Number(base), Number(logaritmo));
  }
  vis.value = resultado;

}
```

```html
<form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
  <p id="elemento"></p>
  <input id="log" type="text"/>
  <input id="base" type="text"/>
  <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value="" />
  <input type="button" name="logaritmo" class="formula" value="log" title="logaritmo" onclick="calculoLogaritmo()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Uma duvida! O que isso ${logaritmo} faz?

Comment: Ele insere o valor da variável dentro do template de string, resultando na string com o valor dentro